# passing viewmodel from JS to controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

I have two classes: Person and ViewModelPerson.
ViewModelPerson's Constructor gets 3 arguments: "Person" and two ints.

I have a seperate JS file, where I get a person's details and then I need to send the details to a function in my controller that gets a single "ViewModelPerson" argument.

**How do I create a "ViewModelPerson" in JS to pass it on ajax to the controller?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are after a **custom model binder**.

1. Build a custom model binder by implementing IModelBinder (we will call it PersonViewModelCustomBinder) which will create a Person object by loading person’s properties from the from collection the use it to create the PersonViewModel
2. Decorate your controller action with PersonViewModelCustomBinder, someting along the lines of..

   **public ActionResult PersonSave([ModelBinder(typeof(PersonViewModelCustomBinder))] PersonViewModel pvm)**
3. From your javascript function, use $.ajax to post the data to the controller action